# Nothing happens when automatically sending bump via a bot for discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots, bump

I aim to create a node.js bot for Discord allowing me to bump SEO site bots automatically. The bump works when done manually and my bot works very well and sends automatic bump messages but nothing happens. Do you know if the developers of SEO bots block the sending of automatic bumps from homemade bots?

Thank you in advance for your answer,

Answer (score 0):

These sites are blocking the use of bots here. You could bypass this with a self-bot, but they're heavily against Discord's ToS.